# Clear drop down cell content depend on another cell value change

Tags: excel, vba

want clear C1 cell value (Drop down cell) after I change A2 value to grater than 2.I have list box for A2 cell change.I followed below vba code.Need to modify it.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Range("A2").Value > 2 Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Range("A2").Value > 2 Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Change 1 to 4 but not cleared.after i try to change drop down value i got compile error.

Comment: I think @BigBen is trying to say `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) If Me.Range("A2").Value > 2 Then Range("C1").ClearContents End If End Sub`

Comment: @KarenSandria the code in your comment above is missing one `End If` (to close your first `If Not` statement).

Comment: can anyone help me to correct this code.I tried below `code`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
    If Me.Range("A2").Value > 2 Then
        Range("C1").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Edit your Question with the latest code you tried. There are two If conditions and you are completing the second on the same line its ok or I agree with @SamuelEverson

Comment: Unfortunately, changes made to cell A2 by selecting an item from the listbox will not trigger the Change event.

Comment: I think removing the first If condition of intersection will do it

Comment: An alternative would be to use an ActiveX listbox, where you would have the Click event available for your listbox.

Comment: @Domenic - you could also assign a macro to the form control listbox.

Comment: @BigBen Ah yes, very true, thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, changes made to cell A2 by selecting an item from the listbox will not trigger the Change event.

An alternative would be to use an ActiveX listbox, where you would have the Click event available for your listbox.

Or another alternative would be to assign a macro to your listbox, as @BigBen has mentioned in his comments.

Comment: Upvoted. Never knew this... probably cause I steer clear of forms and controls in general :-)

Comment: I'll just be removing my answer now... :P

Comment: can any one help to assign a macro for list box from form control

Comment: To assign a macro to your listbox, you can simply right-click the listbox, and then select `Assign Macro` from the context menu.  Then enter the name of your macro in the `Macro Name` box or select it from the list, and click OK.